# Moving a floated div down while maintaining word wrap

Tags: css, css-float

Is it possible to simply move a floated element down, while still maintaining the flow of the rest of the document? For example how can i go from this

http://jsfiddle.net/2fWjJ/

To this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2fWjJ/1/

While maintaining a word wrap on the content div? Margin obviously not the way to go.

The solution can't be to move the second floated div into my content div.

Code from second jsfiddle:

HTML

```
<div id="info">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a sollicitudin leo.</p>
</div>
<div id="quote">
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus turpis malesuada, sagittis ipsum in, porttitor leo..</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>Proin dapibus nibh tortor, et interdum lacus elementum ut. In in ligula consequat, hendrerit purus ut, eleifend ipsum. Quisque rutrum turpis a tincidunt gravida. Nam tempor nisi elit, nec egestas sapien accumsan ut. Proin a interdum sapien, id commodo velit. Suspendisse convallis non neque eget sodales. Cras adipiscing ligula nisl, ut mattis nibh feugiat vitae. Morbi placerat purus tincidunt placerat dignissim.</p>
<p>Etiam non nibh vitae turpis venenatis accumsan. Maecenas in leo vitae justo malesuada porta. Morbi condimentum aliquam dolor eget dictum. Fusce rhoncus bibendum nibh, vulputate sollicitudin quam vestibulum nec. Donec commodo augue vel eleifend vestibulum. Phasellus eget libero sed eros egestas tempus sed nec ipsum. Nulla eu fermentum odio. Nunc laoreet ipsum sit amet imperdiet commodo. Mauris laoreet consectetur justo, ac pharetra lorem sagittis at. Fusce consectetur felis in sagittis volutpat. Quisque egestas rhoncus risus, at ullamcorper ligula aliquam id. Sed non arcu eget magna hendrerit commodo ut at est. Mauris erat ipsum, congue sit amet tincidunt in, mollis eget lacus. Ut adipiscing posuere vulputate. Proin in dapibus velit, vel iaculis quam. Suspendisse nec posuere urna.</p>
<p>Duis ac aliquet mi. Fusce velit nisl, mollis eget cursus blandit, egestas id orci. Phasellus pulvinar urna nec viverra tempor. Donec rhoncus elit tellus, nec sodales nisl gravida ut. Sed vitae placerat eros. Donec suscipit euismod molestie. Sed posuere non justo vitae laoreet. Aenean vitae elit dui. Donec faucibus nisl dui, vitae facilisis purus pretium ac. Aenean dolor massa, tincidunt non elementum ut, porttitor ut tortor. Proin dapibus nibh tortor, et interdum lacus elementum ut. In in ligula consequat, hendrerit purus ut, eleifend ipsum. Quisque rutrum turpis a tincidunt gravida. Nam tempor nisi elit, nec egestas sapien accumsan ut. Proin a interdum sapien, id commodo velit.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#info
{
    width: 125px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#quote
{
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: fiddles don't stay around forever. Instead of linking to these, which, in my opinion, has become a habit of inconvenience on the site, please make an effort of forming a well expressed thourough question INLINE, here on SO space. In other words, please DO GO INTO A TOO WORDY explanation.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I've looked at it but can'n figure out what you want, and what word-wrap has to do with it.

Comment: @veelen i want the content div to wrap into the space `margin-top:100px` has made instead of there just being a blank space.
@amn point taken i will re-write my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your html to this (if possible?)

```
<div id="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a sollicitudin leo.</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Proin dapibus nibh tortor, et interdum lacus elementum ut. In in ligula consequat, hendrerit purus ut, eleifend ipsum. Quisque rutrum turpis a tincidunt gravida. Nam tempor nisi elit, nec egestas sapien accumsan ut. Proin a interdum sapien, id commodo velit. Suspendisse convallis non neque eget sodales. Cras adipiscing ligula nisl, ut mattis nibh feugiat vitae. Morbi placerat purus tincidunt placerat dignissim.</p>
    <p>Etiam non nibh vitae turpis venenatis accumsan. Maecenas in leo vitae justo malesuada porta. Morbi condimentum aliquam dolor eget dictum. Fusce rhoncus bibendum nibh, vulputate sollicitudin quam vestibulum nec. Donec commodo augue vel eleifend vestibulum. Phasellus eget libero sed eros egestas tempus sed nec ipsum. Nulla eu fermentum odio. Nunc laoreet ipsum sit amet imperdiet commodo. Mauris laoreet consectetur justo, ac pharetra lorem sagittis at. Fusce consectetur felis in sagittis volutpat. Quisque egestas rhoncus risus, at ullamcorper ligula aliquam id. Sed non arcu eget magna hendrerit commodo ut at est. Mauris erat ipsum, congue sit amet tincidunt in, mollis eget lacus. Ut adipiscing posuere vulputate. Proin in dapibus velit, vel iaculis quam. Suspendisse nec posuere urna.</p>
    <p id="quote">In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus turpis malesuada, sagittis ipsum in, porttitor leo..</p>
    <p>Duis ac aliquet mi. Fusce velit nisl, mollis eget cursus blandit, egestas id orci. Phasellus pulvinar urna nec viverra tempor. Donec rhoncus elit tellus, nec sodales nisl gravida ut. Sed vitae placerat eros. Donec suscipit euismod molestie. Sed posuere non justo vitae laoreet. Aenean vitae elit dui. Donec faucibus nisl dui, vitae facilisis purus pretium ac. Aenean dolor massa, tincidunt non elementum ut, porttitor ut tortor. Proin dapibus nibh tortor, et interdum lacus elementum ut. In in ligula consequat, hendrerit purus ut, eleifend ipsum. Quisque rutrum turpis a tincidunt gravida. Nam tempor nisi elit, nec egestas sapien accumsan ut. Proin a interdum sapien, id commodo velit.</p>
</div>
```

and your css to this:

```
#info
{
    width: 125px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#quote
{
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

See it in action on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwvanveelen/2fWjJ/4/)

Comment: Is this possible without moving the paragraph into the content div? Unfortunately I cant restructure the HTML. The end result of your JS fiddle is what I want to achieve.

Comment: No. The only way should be to position your #quote absolute. But that removes it from the page flow, so that the other text cant wrap around it anymore (it's just placed above/below, because it's no longer part of the page flow).